# Simple Java math operations

Tags: java, math, numbers

I'm making a BMI calculator that doesn't seem to be working.

I keep getting 0 as my answer, when it should be 15.7

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public class ass10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    bmi(223,100);
    }
    public static bmi(int w, int h){
        double result;
        result = (w/(h*h))*703
        System.out.println(result)             
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're missing two semicolons at the last two lines. And as I mentioned in your other recent question, capitalize the first letter of class names (convention) :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, if you take an int/int, you get an int, rounded to the lower number (`99/100=0`). You want to cast it as a float, or better yet, a double.

```
public static void bmi(int w, int h){
    double result;
    result = ((double)w/(h*h))*703;
    System.out.println(result);         
}
```

I also fixed 2 missing semicolons for you;-) And your function wouldn't work without a return type, so I set that to void.

Comment: And it won't matter, as the integer division is already done before casting.

Comment: Fixed the casting. No return type was specified.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto.. So, is this method valid without a return type even if it was not specified?

Comment: +1 Actually int/int rounds towards 0 not the nearest. 99/100 => 0

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Added that very example.